# Magento2 create Product API

Tags: magento2, product, api

> I'm creating Product create / Edit API for admin.

In product edit API some attributes are in `custom_attribute` section(most of newly create) some are in `extension_attribute` and remain are directly within attribute code i
'm passing in the payload.

My question when creating Product how can I separate which attributes are within which section.directly,`custom_attribute` section or within `extension_attribute` section.because an at a time of product creation I can not separate attributes in section by using attribute set.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take them step by step:

- **top level attributes** (name, sku, price, ...): this are the attributes that have a setter / getter in `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`. But they have to be attributes. For example there is a getter `getOptions` that gives you the custom options of the product. That one is not an attribute getter.
- **extension attributes**: these are entities (or fields) related to the product that you don't store in the main product tables (`catalog_product_entity_*`). You will find them defined in the `extension_attributes.xml` files for the entity `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`.  If you want to know all of them look in the for the string `extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface"` in all `extension_attributes.xml` files. You can add one or more yourself following the same procedure.
- **custom attributes**. All other product attributes that do not appear in the top level.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my short answer (I will update later)

For product custom attributes:

- Those attributes will be added to `custom_attributes` "automatically". And, they are eav attributes.
- You can find them in `eav_attribute` table.
- <del>`is_user_defined` is true (1) in `eav_attribute`.</del>

For product extension attributes, you need:

- Declare your attribute in `extension_attributes.xml`.
- Working with Service contract. Adding more logic to work with them. For example, showing them, saving them. For example: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html
- We can use extension attributes for complicated logic like inventory.

Product extension attribute is more complicated than custom attribute.

Marius's answer is more clear.

Comment: do you have any solution for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298674/magento-2-inventory-management-based-on-customer-groups