# Magento 2 Inventory Management based on customer Groups

Tags: magento2.3.2

I have a condition for example lets suppose I have a product having quantity equals to 100,

**Case:1**
 b2b customer who can purchase max of 20 products and after that he cannot order any more of that product

**Case:2**
now I have b2c customer who can order max 3 quantity of that product and after he cannot purchase any more.

Is there anyway to fix that issue ? Or anyone have tried this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**To achive the above, You can do by the following approch**

1. Create a table to track customer purches information (`e.g customer
   id, purchase product id, purchased qty`).
2. Create a event-observer class for every add to cart.
3. Validate whether **B2B**, **B2C** customer is eligible for buy requestd qty
   or not.